# Working with array - resorting based by the values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$selected_emails = 
array(6) {
  [16781]=> "xxx@gmail.com",
  [16782]=> "yyy@gmail.com",
  [16785]=> "xxx@gmail.com,yyy@gmail.com",
  [16789]=> "yyy@gmail.com",
  [16751]=> "xxx@gmail.com,yyy@gmail.com,zzz@gmail.com",
  [16729]=> "zzz@gmail.com,bbb@gmail.com",
}
```

The `keys` of the above array are the news ids, and the `values` are the emails which are gonna get that news(news id) by email.

I want to send an email for the emails in the above array, so I need the above array to be sorted by the email addresses(unique) with the values of the news ids they need to get, so the above array should be like:

```
$final_array = 
array(4) {
    [xxx@gmail.com] => "16781,16785,16751",
    [yyy@gmail.com] => "16782,16789,16751",
    [zzz@gmail.com] => "16751,16729,",
    [bbb@gmail.com] => "16729", 
}
```

So in the new array I know which news I need to send for each email.

Unfortunately I have no idea how I could do this, I have done to many `foreach`s but none of the are working fine.

How this could be achieved? Thanks

Comment: Can you show us one of your attempts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$final_array = array();

foreach ($selected_emails as $newsletter => $emails) {
    foreach (explode(',', $emails) as $email) {
        $final_array[$email][] = $newsletter;
    }
}

var_dump($final_array);
```

Note that this stores the newsletter ids as an *array of ids* instead of a comma separated list, which is much easier to work with.

Demo: http://3v4l.org/605SI

Comment: What about duplicates?

Comment: If you really want to have coma separated list you can add this `$final_array=array_map(function($value){return implode(',', $value);}, $final_array);`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the array_flip() function in php, it swaps the keys with the values:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

Then sort the array by it keys with ksort().

```
$selected_emails = array_flip($selected_emails);
ksort($selected_emails);
print_r($selected_emails);
```

Comment: This does nothing to collect the ids. You will lose all the duplicates when you flip.